# Unique Architecture Around the World - Medieval Era

Tags: medieval, architecture

I'm designing a medieval era game(dark/light magic influenced) and I need some inspiration for the architecture.

Criteria:

- Preferred 14th century or lower
- Celtic/Nordic is preferred, but any culture is fine
- It can be highly decorated, or covered in moss and dirt. I don't mind a bit
- Preferred stone or wood-based
- No houses, unless churches, occasionally castles.

A perfect example of unique architecture to my standards would be the [inverted tower](https://www.google.com/search?q=inverted%20tower&oq=inverted%20tower&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.3007j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), which I found by chance.

I've googled keywords for this question (such as "old 14th century unique architecture"), however more than half isn't all that unique, and the other is modern "architecture", like [this](http://amzhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/remarkable-architecture-house-on-architecture-with-house-design-is-a-blend-of-old-traditional-house-design-ideas-and.jpg). I don't want *that* kind of unique.

EDIT:

After googling a little bit, I've found quite a few link that have proven helpful for both architecture and nature sights. I've listed one below(I'll update with more links when I find more):

- http://www.youramazingplaces.com/the-100-most-beautiful-and-breathtaking-places-in-the-world-in-pictures-part-1/

Comment: I like the request for architecture, tag created.

Comment: Shyy Guy, This question looks like it will be closed.  If you can specify what type of building you are looking for, perhaps it server a specific function, is created with specific materials, or in a specific terrain and ask for specific examples it would be better suited to the format of the site.  If you have questions on how to better this question posting it on the sandbox would be a good idea.  http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: @James, thanks for creating the tag! Also, I've tried to be specific for the type of architecture. Are the listings under the criteria not specific enough?

Comment: @James Good idea; I've added it to a few other questions.

Comment: Another underground structure: the [Basilica Cistern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_Cistern) in Istanbul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most dungeon structures are simply going to be rooms of varying sizes, connected by various tunnels. If you are looking for something different than that, then I would suggest searching for various architectural types with the word "dungeon" attached to them. You will get a lot of charts and grid maps for various Dungeons and Dragons type maps, which you can adapt to your own needs.

Tomb of Horrors (A well known early D&D module) came up with this image:
[image: Tomb of Horrors]

Other things I have seen are structures built into dormant volcanoes, cities intact at the bottom of the sea, inverted pyramids built underground instead of up. You can also look at beehives, anthills, termite mounds, and just enlarge them for use.

Additionally, you can take modern day topological structures and adapt them, for example a sewer map of Memphis from 1880:
[image]

Added for the edit:
My favorite searches would be in the images section, and consist of either "fantasy medieval architecture", medieval architecture, or dungeons dragons architecture. All of those will have real world examples, as well as established fantasy architecture as well. You can then pick and choose.

Most of the towns and such will be clustered around the local castle, especially in the Celtic region. You'd have the local laird in his castle, a few surrounding shops and homes, with the farmers and such being more outlying.

For example, here is a 14th century Irish castle:
[image]

Note the main central fort structure with the walls, and towards the left you can see where the original village would have started, having been replaced with more modern structures.

Comment: I realized the popular definition of a dungeon is (rightfully so), underground. I shouldn't have said that. The type of places/architecture that I'm looking for is similar to Dark Souls games. I prefer real world examples/pictures, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Adding the "fantasy" keyword turns up a bit of drawn/CGI art, and a few bits of real architecture images as well. I think that is all I needed, just better keywords for searching. Thanks!

Comment: @ShyyGuy - No problem. Glad it helped you out!